# Include SQL file between BEGIN ... END returns error SQL80001

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem when I try to include SQL file between a BEGIN ... END statement.
Here is my sql script :

```
IF @Statement   
BEGIN

:r .\myfile.sql

END
```

When I try to execute it, I have the following error :

```
Error   160 SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near ':'.
```

Does anybody knows what I am doing wrong ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: How are you running this SQL; directly, or using `SQLCMD`?

Comment: Actually this is a PostDeployment script inside a SQLPROJ, and I get this error when I'm building it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BEGIN and END are Transact-SQL statements. They get parsed and executed by SQL Server engine

`:r` is a sqlcmd extension. The sqlcmd tool uses it to change whatever it sends to SQL Server.

If you send `:r` to the engine (which you did) you will get a syntax error. `:r` can be used in sqlcmd, in SSMS when sqlcmd mode is enabled, or you can sue a custom library to do it in your app, like [`DbUtilSqlCmd`](https://github.com/rusanu/DbUtilSqlCmd).

Comment: And is there any way to include a file inside BEGIN ... END statement without using `:r` ?

Comment: [How to: Enable SQLCMD mode in the Transact-SQL Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833182(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could try enabling SQLCMD mode by hitting the button at the top right corner of the page. (At least I think that's where is should be)

Hope that helps.

//Houdini